# Are there Magic cards that counter activated abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there any Magic cards that nullify activated abilities?

*Edit: My apologies for such an easily query-able answer. I was not aware of the existence o such comprehensive databases and easily-searchable databases like magiccards.info before posting these questions. I will surely do more research from now on. Thank you!*

Comment: You really need to research more rather that machine gunning this site with your short questions that can be searched via advanced search in some magic card database site.

Answer (score 2):

Several cards that counter activated abilities. They are

- **[Ayesha Tanaka](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ayesha%20Tanaka)** (only from artifact sources)
- **[Azorius Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorius%20Guildmage)**
- **[Bind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bind)**
- **[Brown Ouphe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brown%20Ouphe)** (only from artifact sources)
- **[Interdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Interdict)** (only from artifacts, creatures, enchantments, and lands. It also prevents that permanent from activating abilities for the rest of the turn.)
- **[Ouphe Vandals](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ouphe%20Vandals)** (only from artifact sources. Also destroys the artifact.)
- **[Rimewind Cryomancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rimewind%20Cryomancer)**
- **[Rust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rust)** (only from artifacts)
- **[Squelch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Squelch)**
- **[Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle)** (also hits triggered abilities)
- **[Trickbind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trickbind)** (also hits triggered abilities, and prevents that permanent from activating abilities for the rest of the turn)
- **[Voidmage Husher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidmage%20Husher)**
- **[Voidslime](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidslime)** (also hits triggered abilities)

There are also cards that prevent activated abilities from being activated. You can find cards that do that with a Gatherer search for ["can't be activated"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5B%22can%27t%20be%20activated%22%5D) There are a bunch of these, but the highlights are

- **[Arrest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arrest)** (An aura that prevents the creature from attacking, blocking, or activating abilities)
- **[Linvala, Keeper of Silence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Linvala%2C%20Keeper%20of%20Silence)** (Prevents any creature your opponent controls from activating abilities)
- **[Null Rod](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Null%20Rod)** (Prevents all artifacts from activating abilities)
- **[Phyrexian Revoker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phyrexian%20Revoker)** (Lets you name a card, and stops any permanent with that name from activating abilities)
- **[Pithing Needle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pithing%20Needle)** (Basically the same effect as Phyrexian Revoker, but can't stop mana abilities)

As Michael Snook points out, [Time Stop](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Stop) and [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite) end the turn immediately, and that includes exiling anything on the stack, including activated abilities.

Comment: Ayesha Tanaka can only counter activated abilities from artifact sources.

Comment: You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Azori**us** not *ous*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's several: [this Gatherer search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5Bcounter%5D+%5Btarget%5D+%5Bactivated%5D+%5Bability%5D) covers cards with the words *"counter target activated ability"* in their rules text (not necessarily in that exact order), which covers that exact phrase and small variatons on it.

At the time of writing:

- Instants that counter any activated ability: [Bind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bind), [Squelch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Squelch), [Stifle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stifle), [Trickbind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trickbind), and [Voidslime](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidslime).
- Instants that only deal with certain varieties: [Interdict](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Interdict) and [Rust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rust)
- Creatures which counter any activated ability: [Azorius Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorius%20Guildmage), [Voidmage Husher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidmage%20Husher), and [Rimewind Cryomancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rimewind%20Cryomancer)
- Creatures which only deal with certain varieties: [Ouphe Vandals](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ouphe%20Vandals), [Ayesha Tanaka](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ayesha%20Tanaka) and [Brown Ouphe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brown%20Ouphe)

For far more nuclear options, there's [Time Stop](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Stop) amd [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite), which exile *everything* on the stack as part of the turn ending.